# C# calling un-implemented method in abstract interface implementation

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class

There's an interface `OptionsSet` and an abstract class `StringBasedOptionsSet`.

```
interface OptionsSet {

    string getString(string key);

    int getInt(string key);

}

abstract class StringBasedOptionsSet : OptionsSet {

    int getInt(string key) {
        string v = getString(key);
        try {
            return Convert.ToInt32(v);
        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            if (exc is FormatException || exc is OverflowException) {
                return 0;
            }
            throw;
        }
    }

}
```

Why can't I call the `getString(string)` method from `StringBasedOptionSet.getInt(string)`?

```
csmade/StringBasedOptionsSet.cs(21,36): error CS0103: The name `getString' does not exist in the current context
csmade/StringBasedOptionsSet.cs(32,25): error CS0103: The name `getString' does not exist in the current context
```

I also tried invoking `OptionsSet.getString(key)` and `base.getString(key)` which leads to *non-static method* / *object does not contain definition for getString* errors.

**Edit**: That `StringBasedOptionsSet` does not implemented the `OptionsSet` interface was a mistake while stripping down the example. It *does* implemented the interface in my actual code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the method as an `abstract` stub or proper method (optionally `virtual`) inside your abstract class definition:

```
public abstract string getString(string key);
```

Or:

```
public virtual string getString(string key)
{
    return null;
}
```

<sub>This is the [template method pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternTemplate.aspx).</sub>

If you intend to force derived types to provide `getString` then an `abstract` method is required. If you do not want to force it, but allow it to be overridden then a default `virtual` method is required.

Note that your abstract class does not need to implement the interface directly, this can be done at the derived class and the interface will still be satisfied so long as the methods are defined correctly:

```
interface IFoo
{
    string GetFoo();
}

abstract class FooBase
{
    public virtual string GetFoo()
    {
        return "Adam";
    }
}

class Foo : FooBase, IFoo
{
}
```

However, you probably wouldn't want to do this anyway, this type of design seems a little nonsensical.

Also, C# naming convention favours title case for method names, so `GetInt` and `GetString`. Naming convention for interfaces is to prefix with `I`: `IOptionSet`.

Answer (score 1):

Because StringBasedOptionsSet doesn't implement the interface, your class should be:

```
interface OptionsSet {

    string getString(string key);

    int getInt(string key);

}

abstract class StringBasedOptionsSet : OptionsSet {

    int getInt(string key) {
        string v = getString(key);
        try {
            return Convert.ToInt32(v);
        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            if (exc is FormatException || exc is OverflowException) {
                return 0;
            }
            throw;
        }
    }

}
```

You might also need to define the function again in the abstract class.

Comment: Uups, my example code was missing the implementation. When I actually tried it, it *did* implement the interface.

Comment: The fact that the abstract class wasn't implementing the interface isn't the reason for the compiler errors. It's the lack of the `getString` method in the class that is doing it. Implementing the interface will simply create the next compiler error that the class doesn't implement it properly. The class doesn't actually need to implement the interface at all, that can be done on derived classes and the base class methods will satisfy the interface, but that is largely nonsensical.

Comment: @NiklasR please provide correct code.  The compiler error you are getting based on the code supplied is because you are trying to call a method that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, your abstract class should implement the interface (since it seems to be a concrete base implementation of it) and implement getString() as abstract methode as Adam suggested.

The result would be

```
abstract class StringBasedOptionsSet : OptionsSet
{
    public abstract string getString(string key);

    public int getInt(string key) 
    {
        string v = getString(key);
        try {
            return Convert.ToInt32(v);
        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            if (exc is FormatException || exc is OverflowException) {
                return 0;
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```